# How can a Styled Components Theme be passed as Props to a Material UI component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, accordion, styled-components

I have spent 9 hours searching for a resolution to this any nothing I can find anywhere appears to work.

I am writing a React component in typescript.

I have a simple use of the Material UI Accordian:

```
const Accordion = withStyles({

root:{
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(193, 195, 191)',
    
},
rounded:{
    '&:last-child':{
    borderBottomLeftRadius:'0px',
    borderBottomRightRadius:'0px',
    },
    '&:first-child':{
        borderTopLeftRadius:'0px',
        borderTopRightRadius:'0px',
        }
}
})(MuiAccordian);
```

All I am trying to do is pass in my Styled Components theme so I can apply it as the root=>backgroundColor value.

I am sure some wizard in here will spot my issue immediately - can I please ask someone to simply show how to pass in a theme of type DefaultTheme object as props to the withStyles method?

Many thanks for any help.

**EDIT - CODE SOLUTION**

With thanks to @filippofilip below, the links in his answer point to information that allowed me to solve this.

The working code is:

```
const Accordion = withStyles(
    {
      root: (props:DefaultTheme) => ({
        backgroundColor: props.colors.backgroundColor,
    }),
      rounded: {
        '&:last-child': {
          borderBottomLeftRadius: '0px',
          borderBottomRightRadius: '0px',
        },
        '&:first-child': {
          borderTopLeftRadius: '0px',
          borderTopRightRadius: '0px',
        },
      },
    },
    { withTheme: true },
  )(MuiAccordian);
```

You will note the slight difference in parsing the typed props which is of type DefaultTheme from Styled Components.

To call this from implementation, I used the useContext hook to retrieve the Styled Components Theme and pass that to the props:

```
export default function MyAccordianComponent() {
  
  const themeContext = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const classes = useStyles(themeContext);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Accordion {...themeContext} defaultExpanded >

---fill in the rest of the component below
```

I hope this assists someone else looking for this or similar to work with Styled Components, Typescript and Material UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to checkout this documentation example
https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props

Usually theme is inside of props argument or as a second argument coming from that function.

**EDIT:** I found it in documentation you should explicitly specify that you want have theme inside `props` object.

So just use it like this:

```
const Accordion = withStyles(
  {
    root: {
      backgroundColor: props => props.theme.backgroundColor,
    },
    rounded: {
      '&:last-child': {
        borderBottomLeftRadius: '0px',
        borderBottomRightRadius: '0px',
      },
      '&:first-child': {
        borderTopLeftRadius: '0px',
        borderTopRightRadius: '0px',
      },
    },
  },
  { withTheme: true },
)(MuiAccordian);
```

To checkout all other available options look [HERE](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component)

Comment: - I will certainly mark your answer as correct because it points to the solution documentation. The code you have shown doesn't work, but it was so close that I could finally figure it out with your help and the links you provided. I will edit my question to show the solution that worked for me.

Comment: @MrWilliams Hi I'am glad that it helped you. Yes please update the answer with correct working example. I was just writing quick snippet to editor so maybe I've missed something.